# Catch not reached on error

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have main windows form on which i have user control. From there I do some operation related to database. During database process I show user additional windows form so he can see nice circural graphic in meantime. I use task to place mentioned database process and from there if error occurs I want to show error message from try/catch. Unfortunetly MessageBox.Show is not showing up when i do tests - catch is even not reached. Could you help me out what is wrong. I am talking about this line in catch statment:

```
Catch sqlex As Exception
pic.Invoke(Sub() MessageBox.Show(pic, sqlex.Message))
```

Here's circural window's form code:

```
Public Class FrmCircularProgress
    Sub New(progressType As DevComponents.DotNetBar.eCircularProgressType)
        InitializeComponent()
        CircularProgress1.ProgressBarType = progressType
        StartCircular()
    End Sub

    Public Sub StartCircular()
        Me.CircularProgress1.IsRunning = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopCircular()
        Me.CircularProgress1.IsRunning = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is example how i use it with Task:

```
Dim createArticle As New Artikel

                    Dim pic As New FrmCircularProgress(eCircularProgressType.Donut)
                    Dim tsk As Task(Of Boolean) = Task.Factory.StartNew(Of Boolean)(Function()
                                                                                        '--Run lenghty task
                                                                                        Dim resu = False
                                                                                        Try
                                                                                            resu = createArticle.ProcessArticle(_artikelsAndTheirVariationsFinal)
                                                                                            '--Close form once done (on GUI thread)

                                                                                        Catch sqlex As Exception
                                                                                            pic.Invoke(Sub() MessageBox.Show(pic, sqlex.Message))
                                                                                                                                                                             Finally
                                                                                            pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() pic.StopCircular()))
                                                                                            pic.Invoke(New Action(Sub() pic.Close()))
                                                                                        End Try

                                                                                        Return resu
                                                                                    End Function)

                    '--Show the form
                    pic.ShowDialog()
                    Task.WaitAll(tsk)
...
```

And just for you to see example database process in our case ProcessArticle which is returning either true or false

```
Public Function ProcessArticle(artikel As ArticlesVariations) As Boolean

        Dim result = True
        Dim strcon = New AppSettingsReader().GetValue("ConnectionString", GetType(System.String)).ToString()

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(strcon)
            '-- Open generall connection for all the queries
            connection.Open()
            '-- Make the transaction.
            Dim transaction As SqlTransaction
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)

            Dim newArticleRowId As Integer = 0
            Dim articleIndex As Integer = 0
            Try
                For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Artikel) In artikel.collection
                    Dim ckey As Integer = kvp.Key
                    articleIndex = kvp.Key              'save article key
                    Dim data As Artikel = kvp.Value

                    '-- If given article contains images list (artikel_images is a list with pictures associated with article)
                    If Not IsNothing(artikel.collection(articleIndex).ArtikelImages) Then
                        For Each img In artikel.collection(articleIndex).ArtikelImages
                            '--Insert article's images if exists
                            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO T_Article_Image (Path, FK_Artikel_ID, Position) VALUES (@Path, @FK_Artikel_ID, @Position)", connection)
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                cmd.Connection = connection
                                cmd.Transaction = transaction
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", img.Path)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Artikel_ID", newArticleRowId)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", img.Position)
                                cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                            End Using
                        Next
                    End If

                    '-- If given article contains articles variations list (artikel_variation_attributes is a list with variations associated with article)
                    If Not IsNothing(artikel.collection(articleIndex)._artikel_variation_attributes) Then
                        For Each var In artikel.collection(articleIndex)._artikel_variation_attributes

                            '--Insert article's images if exists
                            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO T_Artikel_T_Variation (FK_Variation_VariationAttribute_ID, FK_Artikel_ID, Position) VALUES (@FK_Variation_VariationAttribute_ID, @FK_Artikel_ID, @Position)", connection)
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                                cmd.Connection = connection
                                cmd.Transaction = transaction
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Variation_VariationAttribute_ID", New Variation_VariationAttribute(var.FkVariationId, var.FkVariationAttributeId).GetId())
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Artikel_ID", newArticleRowId)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Position", var.Position)
                                cmd.ExecuteScalar()
                            End Using
                        Next
                    End If

                Next
                transaction.Commit()
            Catch ex As Exception
                result = False
                '-- Roll the transaction back.
                Try
                    transaction.Rollback()
                Catch ex2 As Exception
 result = False
                End Try

            End Try
        End Using

        Return result
    End Function
```

Comment: Could you make a short, reproducible example out of it ? Remove references to database, just make it always throw an exception, and try to catch that. Always try to reduce your problem before seeking advice.

Comment: @Neolisk i already cutted a lot, from my point of view it's pretty clear.

Comment: Just ask your wife about how points-of-view differs between persons!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not expect your catch to be reached.  In your ProcessArticle function you have another Try ..  Catch  If there is an error in the SQL operation, this is where it will be caught.  You then return false!  So the calling routine does not catch the error, because it has already been handled gracefully.  If you want to catch the error in your calling routine, then you will need to Raise an error from your catch in the ProcessArticle function.

You could change your Try Catch in ProcessArticle to

```
    Catch ex As Exception
        result = False
        '-- Roll the transaction back.
        Try
            transaction.Rollback()
        Catch ex2 As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Rollback failed after first exception.", ex2)
        End Try
        Throw New Exception("Rollback succeeded after exception.", ex)
    End Try
```

Sorry it's some time since I did VB, but I think the syntax is correct.  Using this, the calling routine should now catch the Exception (and you will have an Exception with an inner exception).  You will need to examine the inner exception to find the cause.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, from your point of view which way you would choose if you were me - could you post as answer how you would modify it? Thx

Comment: if you still there - i got problem as now if i put message box there and error occurs - message box will be shown (ok) but if user not click ok on it but click in some area of application besides this message box it will be hided so user will see circural form ongoing, thats the new problem.

Comment: Why don't you close the circular form, before posting the message box?